# Handle a Timeline (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, project, timeline

I'm on a pseudo-social app.
We have 3 tables:

```
Users: _id_, username, password, email
Movies: _id_, title, synopsis
Followers: __(#user_id1, #user_id2)__, timestamp
U_Movies: __(#user_id, #movie_id)__, rating, timestamp
```

We want to add a timeline to our app, simple timeline, with recent activities. We don't want a custom timeline (no messages), only activities.

What would be the best way to "create" this timeline ?
Would it be, by creating a "Timeline" table with all activities written (doing an `INSERT INTO timeline` when there is an `INSERT INTO followers` and `U_Movies` ?), or getting with MySQL and `JOIN ON` latest followers activities (with the timestamp, which I think would be heavy if there is many many entries and users), and another advice ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a similar thing recently. Your first idea is probably best, add data to a new table (either by a trigger or another insert)

Presuming your not doing and updates or deletes on the table it should scale quite well. You could also partition the table in MySQL based on a date range. This will keep the performance going after a few years (my first version of this has 140million rows over 4 years and still quick)

Edit - Detecting changes.

Using the TRIGGER route - [Before update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) will allow you to compare columns and then perform an insert into the timeline to give you historical changes.

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
     IF NEW.rating != OLD.rating THEN
       INSERT INTO timeline .. 
     END IF;
 END;
```

Comment: TRIGGERS (which I will discover) seems to be the best (and/or 2 inserts), but the thing is that I'll have to track changes. For example, we don't have only "rating" but also "review", when someone want to change a data, the client will send me "rating=INT&review=TEXT", then i'll UPDATE the DB, even if it's the same data. Is there a way to know which collumns has been updated? Then I will insert in `timeline`the type, new rating/review... Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create TRIGGER which will do insert into third table on change.

See TRIGGERS in mysql docs online.